# Windows XP installation set up drive letters incorrectly

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning

I recently (last night actually) installed Windows XP Professional SP3 onto my eMachine. When it was recognizing partitions on my hard disk, it set my system drive as drive letter L: (not the problem).

The problem is setup assigned letter C: to my System Reserve partition, and I can't change it in Disk Management - it says I cannot change the drive letter of my system or boot partition. The problem is it isn't my boot partition (although it is marked as "System".

Is there a way I can force the drive letter off of that partition? Some programs that I install automatically onto my System Reserve partition, and Windows won't let me modify or delete anything on it.

Comment: If it is marked "System" then it is the partition the computer is booting from.  (The partition marked "Boot" is the partition containing the operating system; daft but true.)  Why do you have a System Reserve partition anyway, did the machine have Vista or Windows 7 installed previously?

Comment: It also has Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12 on it, not that I can access it.

Comment: You could try this, though Windows XP might stop booting properly.  You definitely shouldn't change the drive letter Windows is installed on, but you might get away with changing the drive letter for the System Reserved partition: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/223188

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partition Majic will let you reassign dirve letters. You can choose the boot order in your machine's Bios setup program. You get to setup by pressing a key at start up. Check your mannual for the correct key. You usually do this before the windows logo appears and depending how your startup is configured there may be a prompt at the bottom of your screen.

If you have not gone to far setting up your emachine, you may conside starting from scratch so you can be confident of a stable machine. Your System Reserve partition should contain your facatory reset files. If you have not compromize the reset files then you should be able to still do a factory reset on the box. Then do it right this time. I know this is time consuming but if is better to be confident about the machine.

If you dicide to just change the partition drive letter i sugest backing up all of your data on a weekly basis. This is a good idea anyway but most people dont do it and get burned. Your chances are increased.